# Knitr echo function call with evaluated parameter names

Tags: r, knitr

If I have previously defined

```
n <- 200   
maf <- .2
```

Is there any way to echo

```
snp <- rbinom(n,2,maf)
```

such that it displays as

```
snp <- rbinom(200,2,.2)
```

in the resulting knitr document.

Comment: would `cat(paste0("snp<-rbinom(", n, ", 2, ", maf, ")"))` do it?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to solve the problem in general. I am hoping that there is some option/hook that knitr can use evaluate the parameters first and then echo the function with evaluated parameter names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substitute` like this :

````
```{r ,echo=FALSE}
 substitute(snp <- rbinom(n,2,maf),list(n=n,maf=maf))
 rbinom(n,2,maf)
```

## snp <- rbinom(200, 2, 0.2)
##   [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
##  [36] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
##  [71] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
## [106] 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
## [141] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
## [176] 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 0
````

Comment: This was my thought with `cat` and `paste0` but this is even better but still not quite what the OP seems to be after.  THis may be the best he/she will get. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker I think the best is to wrap `subsitute` and use `match.call` before it , to create dynamically the environment list...